# How to remove the unselected images using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using the selected images only is going to next page. If I have selected the image like(1,2,3), after this I unselected the image (3). On next page I was getting all the images(1,2,3). I don't want unselected image(3). I have tried `localStroage.removeItem` but all the images are getting removed. But I want to remove only the unselected image.

```
  <script>
localStorage.clear();
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.blur').on('click', function(){

        var $$ = $(this);


        if( !$$.is('.checked'))
        {
            $$.addClass('checked');
            $('#imgCheck').prop('checked', true);
            documentid ='' 
            var name=$(this).attr('id');
        //alert(name);
        var test = localStorage.getItem("test");
        //alert(test);
        var obj = [];
        if(test)
        {
            obj= JSON.parse(test); 
        }
            obj.push({"id":  name});
            localStorage.setItem("test",JSON.stringify(obj));
            console.log(obj);
        }
        else
        {

            $$.removeClass('checked');
            $('#imgCheck').prop('checked', false);
            var name=$(this).attr('id');
            //alert(name);
            var test = localStorage.removeItem("test");
            console.log(image);

        }

    })
});
```

please suggest me..